# Enabling EJB Injection into Vaadin 7 UI via Usage of Vaadin-CDI-Integration Addon

Tags: jpa, ejb, vaadin, cdi, code-injection

I wasn't able to successfully integrate the official Vaadin-CDI-Integration-Addon, since after finishing the official integration instructions, the following `Exception` was thrown in case I reloaded the already published URL `localhost:8080/App/?restartApplication`.

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: com.vaadin.server.ServiceException: 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: UI id has already been defined
```

---

The following little workaround is a tested, working solution, which completes the official instructions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to work off the following steps to successfully integrate the official CDI-Integration-Addon into your Vaadin project.

- Do **exactly** as stated [in the official how-to](https://vaadin.com/wiki?p_p_id=36&p_p_lifecycle=0&p_p_state=normal&p_p_mode=view&p_p_col_id=row-1&p_p_col_pos=2&p_p_col_count=4&_36_struts_action=%2Fwiki%2Fview&p_r_p_185834411_nodeName=vaadin.com+wiki&p_r_p_185834411_title=Vaadin+CDI).
- Remove the `?restartApplication` parameter from the URL. This avoids the `Exception`.
- Inject the EJB as shown in the listing below.
- Keep in mind to restart your application manually if necessary!

---

```
@CDIUI
public class ExampleCDIUI extends UI {

    @Inject
    MyLocalBeanInterface myBean;

    @Override
    public void init(VaadinRequest request) {
        Label label = new Label("Hello Vaadin user");
        setContent(label);

        // myBean should be accessible now.

    }

}
```

That's it. I hope this helps :-)